# Argument " " isn't numeric in addition (+) in reniced.conf

Tags: gnome-terminal, system-monitor

A list of
`Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 2.`
shows up when I run the command `sudo reniced` in the terminal
here's what I am getting

```
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 3.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 4.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 5.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 6.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 7.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 8.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 9.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 10.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 11.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 12.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 13.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 14.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 15.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 16.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 17.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 18.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 19.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 20.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 21.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 22.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 23.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 24.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 25.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 26.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 27.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 28.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 29.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 30.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 31.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 32.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 33.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 34.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 35.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 36.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 37.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 38.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 39.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 40.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 41.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 42.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 43.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 44.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 45.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 46.
Argument "     " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 47.
```

I am trying to change priority of an app from reniced.conf, can someone help me to fix this ?
Thanks :)

And I haven't edited the config file yet

Here is the reniced.conf file screenshot. Is anything wrong here ?
[Reniced.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54f9Z.png)

And the output of `ps  H -eo lwp,comm | sed -n '1,10s/^/^/p'` is

```
^      1 systemd
^      2 kthreadd
^      3 rcu_gp
^      4 rcu_par_gp
^      5 kworker/0:0-events
^      6 kworker/0:0H
^      7 kworker/0:1-mm_percpu_wq
^      8 kworker/u8:0-events_unbound
^      9 mm_percpu_wq
```

Comment: Hmm... `/usr/bin/reniced` is a perl script that appears to be hardwired to parse the first 5 characters of the output of the command `ps  H -eo lwp,comm` as PIDs (converting strings to numerics using overloaded addition `+0`). So apparently *something* is causing your `ps` to output empty `lwp` values.

Comment: Can you can explain it for a newbie like me please?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @Priyanshu please [edit] your question to include the output of `ps  H -eo lwp,comm | sed -n '1,10s/^/^/p'`

Comment: @steeldriver can I ask what is this command for? Please be in simple language,as I am a newbie, and I have edited the question, with which you asked. Thanks :)

Comment: @Priyanshu the command prints the output of the `ps` command that `reniced` is parsing in an unambiguous way - and we can see that `ps` on your system is padding the first column to more than 5 characters. I don't know why that is happening  - perhaps because there are more than 99,999 processes running on your machine, or your `ps` version is different from mine (and the one expected by the authors of `reniced`). Regardless, IMHO it's bad practice to rely on `ps` output having a particular field width - so perhaps you should file a bug against the `reniced` package.

Comment: I don't think so that 99999 process are running on my machine, so thier is a possibility that your ps version is different from mine, as said by you I will file a bug report

Comment: @steeldriver Check out this please [link](https://github.com/mmitch/reniced/issues/2) but I think solution is not given. Should I open another bug report for it?

Comment: @Priyanshu yes that link appears to describe the issue exactly - out of curiosity, what is your Ubuntu version and `ps --version`?

Comment: @steeldriver My ubuntu  version is ```Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS``` and when I write ```ps --version``` it shows ```ps from procps-ng UNKNOWN```

Comment: Please note that I have updated ubuntu from 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS when 20.04 LTS was already out, due to some issue, and that is resolved now, I think their is a problem with ```ps --version``` so is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`reniced` **1.21** expects processes list received from `ps` command to have PID of certain length.
With longer PIDs in the operating system, `reniced` crashes when processing the list:

```
Argument " " isn't numeric in addition (+) at /usr/bin/reniced line 435, <PS> line 12.
```

This issue is FIXED UPSTREAM in `reniced` **1.22** (released 17 Jun 2020):
https://github.com/mmitch/reniced/releases/tag/v1.22

The issues was reported to Ubuntu on 2020-11-24, but is still not fixed:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/reniced/+bug/1905485
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=reniced